# What is the purpose of a single pound/hash sign (#) on its own line in the C/C++ preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c, boost, c-preprocessor

I have been looking at the [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) libraries source code, and I have noticed that often there are single pound signs without any preprocessor directives attached to them. I read through the GCC preprocessor manual and specification guide and can't find anything about it.

```
(1) #ifndef BOOST_CONFIG_HPP
(2) #  include <boost/config.hpp>
(3) #endif
(4) #
(5) #if defined(BOOST_HAS_PRAGMA_ONCE)
(6) #  pragma once
(7) #endif
```

On line 4, there is nothing after the pound sign. What effect does this have? Is it defined in the C preprocessor (CPP) specification?

As Boost is a cross-platform library, I would assume that any CPP should parse it correctly. What would the effect/side-effects be of having random pound/hash signs throughout the code?

Comment: Just curious: is CPP a valid abreviation for C preprocessor? It quite confused me when reading OP.

Comment: @Zaibis Eg. the executable name of the preprocessor in the GCC suite is "cpp" (while the compilers are gcc and g++)

Comment: CPP stands for C-Plus-Plus.

Comment: Not entirely. See the first sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: @djeidot "cpp" is ambiguous. That is why people use "c++", or "cxx" (x looks like + turned 45 degrees) when referring to C-Plus-Plus.

Comment: @djeidot No, CPP is the C-PreProcessor. It existed way before C++ even existed.

Comment: @djeidot, [with `Makefile`s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2756681/912144) and autotools, `CPPFLAGS` refers to the preprocessor.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45629176/1967396

Answer (score 188, accepted):

A `#` on its own on a line has no effect at all. I assume it's being used for aesthetic value.

The C standard says:

> **6.10.7 Null directive**
>
> **Semantics**
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# new-line`
>
> has no effect.

The C++ standard says the same thing:

> **16.7  Null directive  [cpp.null]**
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# new-line`
>
> has no effect.

Comment: This doesn't explain the purpose of using it, though, nor give the rationale for its existence.

Comment: _"What effect does this have? Is it defined in the C preprocessor (CPP) specification? ... What would the effect/side-effects be of having random pound/hash signs throughout the code?"_ That's what I answered. It has no effect, but I didn't want to speculate on the author's reason for using it. I have done so now.

Comment: You have been given correct answers that it means nothing to the preprocessor; I'm going to speculate that it may help some other program (such as an IDE or LINT) keep a block of directives together as a logical unit. Some IDEs let programmers expand or collapse blocks of text to help them keep track of the logical structure of the file.

Answer (score 110):

It makes the source code look pretty, that's all.

Highlights the fact that the whole block is a preprocessor section.

And indeed, both the C and C++ preprocessors *must* ignore `#` on a line.

Comment: And also makes navigating easier in some text editors (e.g., `{` or `}` in vim).

Comment: @WChargin, that depends on how you look at it. If you want to navigate to between the two preprocessor blocks, adding `#` would prevent you from using `{` or `}`. In fact, it may be easier to press `}` twice to jump over the block (in the OP's example) than not be able to jump to the middle of the two blocks.

Comment: @Shahbaz Certainly! My rule of thumb is "keep logical units together," so that "paragraph" really means "idea." I would follow this rule with preprocessor declarations, too. Of course, it is a matter of personal style to a large degree.

Answer (score 48):

Always check an authoritative source instead of relying on other resources. C is standardised as ISO 9899::2011, C++ also has an ISO standard. Both are well accepted and the final drafts available by a short search. The C standard states in [6.10.7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.7) (C++ has much the same text):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # new-line
> ```
>
> has no effect.

This is a *null directive*, as much as an `;` without a preceeding expression in the core-language is a *null statement* .

For the preprocessor it is just for formatting/readability to highlight that the lines belong semantically together. (the semicolon OTOH is semantically relevant).